# Why is a space of functions equal to the n-fold product of field F?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

The space of functions whose domain is $S$ and their values lie in $F$ (a field) is shown by:

$$\mathbf{Func}(S,F) = \{f: S \to F\}   (1)$$

In [linear algebra by Peter Petersen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461436117) on page 11 example 1.4.6 is written that if $S = \{1,2,...,n\}$ then:

$$\mathbf{Func}(\{1,2,...,n\},F) = F^n  (2)$$

The book continues that the vectors in $F^n$ can be also thought of functions.
I cannot understand equation 2 and the statement mentioned above. Why is the space of functions equal to the vector space $F^n$?
For example, if $n = 1$, then we have:

$$\mathbf{Func}(\{1\},F) = F$$

How does the space of all functions which their input is 1 equal to the field F?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a natural bijection
$$\mathbf{Func}(\{1,2,...,n\},F) \xrightarrow{\sim} F^n$$

given by sending an element $f\in \mathbf{Func}(\{1,2,...,n\},F)$ to the $n$-uple $(f(1),f(2),\ldots ,f(n))$. This function is bijective. To see this, you can either show that it is both injective and surjective, either exhibit its inverse. To me, the latter is the most direct way here.

The inverse is clearly given by the map that sends an $n$-uple $(y_1,\ldots ,y_n)\in F^n$ to the function $f\in \mathbf{Func}(\{1,2,...,n\},F)$ defined by the relations $\forall i\in\{1,2,...,n\}, f(i)=y_i$.

NB: Note that when writes $\mathbf{Func}(\{1,2,...,n\},F) = F^n$ with an *equal* sign, this is actually a usual abuse of notation. Both sets clearly are not *equal*. Their respective objects are of different nature. However, this equal sign is meant to signify "both objects can be identified in a natural manner". The good notion of "to be identified" depends on the respective algebraic structure of both sets. Actually, here we may also see both sets as $F$-vector spaces. It happens that not only we have a natural bijection between them as sets, but this bijection turns out to be a natural isomorphism between them as $F$-vector spaces. That is, it respects the sum and the extern product by elements of $F$, as it can be easily checked.

Comment: Back in a prior geological era, I was taught to designate the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ as $Y^X$. Anyway, plus one.

Comment: I was taught this way too @Lubin (which was actually 4 years ago).

Comment: @Lubin  It is still used nowadays.  And I like this notation a lot.  I also prefer writing $2^X$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$ for the power set of a set $X$.

Comment: @Suzet Is the following right? We can think of $F^n$ as a vector space over F whose elements are n-tuples and there is a one-to-one correspondence between these n-tuples and the functions (vectors) in the space of functions.

Comment: Oh Lord, are you telling me I’m up to date? Horrors!

Comment: @MOON Yes, and note that we can also, separately, think of $\mathbf{Func}(\{1,2,...,n\},F)$ as a vector space over $F$ in a natural manner. It happens that the correspondance you mention (that is the one I described above) respect the structure of both vector spaces (hence actually is an *isomorphism* between vector spaces).